# How to run R script line by line from linux shell?

Tags: shell, r

I'm used to work on my R scripts with some GUI, so I can easily run commands line-by-line, then pause and inspect my objects as they are created and changed.

I currently need to work with some data on a remote server. Is it possible to run line-by-line using R console or some other application (please, not vi) that does not require real GUI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [ESS](http://ess.r-project.org), the R mode for Emacs, it is trivial to run R code step-by-step.

Emacs, and hence ESS, can be run in text mode (start as `emacs -nw`) as well as graphical mode.

See [the ESS manual](http://ess.r-project.org/Manual/ess.html#Evaluating-code) for info on evaluating code. In particular, the two commands that seem the most helpful to me are:

C-c M-j (ess-eval-line-and-go): Send the line containing point to the ESS process, and returns you to the ESS process buffer as well.

and

C-c M-r (ess-eval-region) : Send the text between point and mark to the ESS process, and returns you to the ESS process buffer as well.

Comment: isn't eval region C-c C-r? At least, that's how I have been doing it.

Comment: a) Someone else edited that into my post.  b) Yes, both are correct. One moves point to the R buffer, the other leaves it in the editing buffer.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I probably should have just pressed C-h k though, and saved you the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your code in a function and then `debug` it so it would run in a step mode. Read `?debug` for more details.